# TFS Trial Edition Licensing Question

Tags: tfs, licensing

My trial of Team Foundation Server has expired. Why can't I just install a fresh copy on a different server and use it for another 90 days?

1. I am using the same source code.
2. I don't want to do this, but my boss is trying to make me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your employer is wanting you to do this to extend your evaluation period and not to use software against the license terms then you might want to try the utility posted at the bottom of the following post instead:

http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2008/01/15/checking-your-tfs-version-and-extending-trials.aspx

TFS doesn't currently migrate well to another TFS instance, so if you were continually moving to a new TFS server every 90-days you wouldn't have a great experience.  Also you be in breach of the EULA and therefore committing a form of software piracy under most legal systems.

If you are doing this to extend your trial then the tool above will give you an extra 30 days and if you talk nicely with your local Microsoft rep then you might be able to get a longer extension.

BTW - [Microsoft BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/) is an excellent program run by Microsoft which provides all their dev tools (including TFS) and is designed for cash strapped start-ups.  Contact your local Microsoft office if you want to find out more about the program.

Good luck,

Martin.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a better answer than I hoped for.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from this being illegal, I would think the hassle of switching to a new server every 90 days will out weigh the cost of just paying for the software.

So you have 3 choices

- pay for the software and get legal
- keep switching servers every 90 days
- switch to a free open source system (subversion?)

There's a 4th choice: you can go to ALL Microsoft events and hope they give out free licenses to TFS at one of the events :)

Comment: But why is it illegal? I need to show something in writing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VS Team Edition? This includes TFS Workgroup which is good for up to 5 users without further licensing.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do this, but I'm sure there's something in employment regulations (wherever you live) about being coerced to break the law, which is effectively what you'd be doing.